# Creating a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I am trying to Create a package MSGG_SESSION with a procedure authenticate that accepts two VARCHAR2
parameters for username and password. Put an package-private NUMBER variable for the
current person ID. If “authenticate” matches a username and password in MSGG_USER , put the
matching PERSON_ID in the new variable. when i put this into oracle sql developer i get and error. i already created a table MSGG_SESSION  and a MSGG_USER table already exists. (PRIV-NUMBER is my package private number variable for the current person ID)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MSGG_SESSION
IS

    PROCEDURE AUTHENTICATE (USERNAME IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2);
    FUNCTION AUTHENTICATED_USER RETURN VARCHAR2;
END MSGG_SESSION;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MSGG_SESSION
IS
    PRIV_NUMBER VARCHAR2(100);

    PROCEDURE AUTHENTICATE (USERNAME_TO_AUTH IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD_TO_USE IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        PRIV_NUMBER := NULL;
        SELECT USERNAME
            INTO PRIV_NUMBER
        FROM
            USER_PASSWORD
        WHERE
            lower(username) = lower(username_to_auth) and password = password_to_use;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            raise NOT_AUTHENTICATED;
        when others then
            raise;
    END AUTHENTICATE;

    FUNCTION GET_USER_ID
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    is
    begin
        return priv_number;
    end get_user_id;

END MSGG_SESSION;
/
```

Comment: Never store passwords as plaintext.  Even if this is only a homework question, it's good to learn now that this code is completely unacceptable.

Comment: ok thank you this is good to know

Answer (score 0):

A few things you did wrong:

- procedures declared in package specification **MUST** match those in the package body in name, number and datatypes of their parameters
- if you are raising an exception, you have to declare it

See comments within the code:

Specification:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MSGG_SESSION IS
  2    -- parameter names must be changed so that they match those in package body, which
  3    -- is a better option as table columns are named USERNAME and PASSWORD
  4    PROCEDURE AUTHENTICATE (USERNAME_to_auth IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD_to_use IN VARCHAR2);
  5    FUNCTION AUTHENTICATED_USER RETURN VARCHAR2;
  6  END MSGG_SESSION;
  7  /

Package created.
```

Body: why do you raise your own exception if nothing is found? I mean, what's wrong with `NO_DATA_FOUND` itself? What benefit does `NOT_AUTHENTICATED` exception brings?

```
SQL> create or replace package body msgg_session is
  2    priv_number varchar2(100);
  3
  4    procedure authenticate (username_to_auth in varchar2, password_to_use in varchar2)
  5    is
  6      -- you didn't declare it
  7      not_authenticated exception;
  8    begin
  9      select username
 10          into priv_number
 11        from user_password
 12      where lower(username) = lower(username_to_auth)
 13        and password = password_to_use;
 14    exception
 15      when no_data_found then
 16        -- now goes the clumsy part of code
 17        begin
 18          raise not_authenticated;
 19        exception
 20          when not_authenticated then
 21            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not authenticated');
 22        end;
 23      when others then
 24        raise;
 25    end authenticate;
 26
 27    -- it exists in the specification, so it must exist in body
 28    function authenticated_user
 29      return varchar2
 30    is
 31    begin
 32      return null;
 33    end;
 34
 35    -- it is local to body (and can't be used out of it)
 36    function get_user_id
 37      return varchar2
 38    is
 39    begin
 40      return priv_number;
 41    end get_user_id;
 42  end msgg_session;
 43  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: i do not really need the NOT_AUTHENTICATED exception i can just make it NO_DATA_FOUND instead

Comment: OK then, even better (and simpler).